# Illegal seek during usage of Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm facing a strange issue. My testing code is pretty straightforward, similar to this [test](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7cb52f53ef65317d5227f5b0ddaa09cbd0b9c0c3/tests/test_trainer.py#L121).
When I don't use pytest, the program finishes smoothly with all tests passing.
When I use pytest with -v -k and --pdb (in -k, I specify the problematic function), the specific test passes.
This indicates that there is no problem in my testing modules.

When I run pytest in the normal way (`pytest tests/filename.py`), I'm getting this error `OSError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek`.
By looking at the trace, I see the issue being raised in `<contextlib._GeneratorContextManager object at ...>`
I'm unable to find much information as to why Illegal seek error arises, and why is it being raised here.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is designed for pytest and not for the [unittest framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)?

Comment: I don't get this error when I test with python. As in python filename.py (where the functions are called by ```unittest.main() method```. This indicates that there is some issue with pytest testing method.

Comment: It seems like there was an issue with wandb (pip package), after uninstalling it, I'm not getting this error.